# sed replace : delete a character between two strings while preserving a regex

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I have a csv file which is delimited by #~#.

there is a field which contains 0 and then n(more than 1) number of '.'(dot).

I need to remove the zero and preserve the later dots. I have to also take care that floating numbers are not affected.

So effectively  replace **#~#0.....#~#**   to    **#~#.....#~#** (dots can be from 1 to any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit the replacement with fields matching the pattern use this

```
$ echo "#~#0.12#~#0.....#~#0.1#~#0.#~#" | sed -r 's/#~#0(\.+)#~#/#~#\1#~#/g'
```

will preserve 0.12 and 0.1 but replace 0..... and 0.

```
#~#0.12#~#.....#~#0.1#~#.#~#
```

`+` in regex means one or more.  Anchoring with the field delimiters will make sure nothing else will be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` you can do:

```
s='#~#0.....#~#'
sed -r 's/(^|#~#)0(\.+($|#~#))/\1\2/g' <<< "$s"
#~#.....#~#

sed -r 's/(^|#~#)0(\.+($|#~#))/\1\2/g' <<< "#~#0.00#~#"
#~#0.00#~#
```

Comment: this also replaces **#~#0.00#~#** to **#~#.00#~#**

Answer (score 0):

```
]$ echo "#~#0.....#~#" | sed 's/#0/#/g'
#~#.....#~#
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the dots ans include all characters that should match:

```
echo "#~#0.1234#~#0.....#~#" | sed 's/#~#0\.\./#~#../g'
```

Using var's will not improve much:

```
delim="#~#"
echo "#~#0.1234#~#0.....#~#" | sed "s/${delim}0\.\./${delim}../g"
```